# Open Source Multilanguage IDE for Linux Desktop

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, ide, desktop-environment

Here are the criteria

- The languages I use most are Python, C++, Bash and a lot of config files for docker, kubernetes etc.
- Must be free and open source
- Great support for dark mode, by default. (which rules out Code::Block)
- Basic functionalities like autocomplete, showing interactive variable lists, call hierarchy, Linting and formatting on save, live method documentations etc.
- Extensively compatible with language server protocols to enforce formatters like Clang, Black, PEP 8 etc.
- Suitable for python development, unlike Code::Block

Right now I am using Atom from Github which I do love, but from the internet, seems it is almost dead and the updates will stop any moment. The most obvious candidate to switch would be VS Code, but I try to avoid microsoft as much as I can (call me prejudiced). I know Github itself belongs to Microsoft now, but still it seems Atom is not as blatantly microsoft as it is.

I am not a real terminal Ninja to use something like Vim and Emacs, hence something like Atom with its customisability, features and extra packages seemed like a perfect sweet spot. What's the closest I can hope for that is not on ventilation?

Comment: Try 1 of this: [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/)
[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: Why don't you take time to learn to use GNU emacs? You could contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` (near Paris in France). I am using emacs since more than twenty years.... Working at https://www-list.cea.fr/ (email is `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr`) and trying to find partners interested by http://refpersys.org/

Answer (score 2):

I think `vs-code` is the only way to go there, optionally you can wait from `Fleet` from `JetBrains` which is actually in closed preview. On the other hand, if you wish to use `atom` you should take a look at `atom-ide` packages which may help you customize the editor to have as many features as `vs-code` does.

Answer (score 0):

Try 1 of this:

[Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/)
[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
Have used both IDEs for C/C++ programming and I know that both suport Python programming as well but as I have never used Python and not going to do it in the future can´t say how good Python suport on each IDE is.
At the moment I am programming only C++ and Code::Blocks is in my opinion the best IDE for this. I´ve never used that dark theme, as I dislike it, so can´t say much about it.
When I used to program Java as well and even some PHP, Eclipse was the IDE of my choice. I don´t know any programming language which is not suported by eclipse, just need to instal the right plugin, which is realy easy to do in Eclipse. That dark theme was also awaible in Eclipse and think it still is.

Answer (score 0):

Try also [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

If you spend some time (a few hours or days) reading documentation about it, you can configure it for your needs.

You can buy books (published by [OReilly](https://www.oreilly.com/)) explaining how to use and configure GNU emacs.

And [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) is free software, and has some tutorial. You can customize it using [Emacs Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp) (including fonts, background and foreground colors, behavior of mouse clicks, behavior of some key presses, etc...).

My `~/.emacs` file is available [here](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/.emacs) and configure my `emacs` editors.